# Optimize Warning for exponential scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, optimization, plot, curve-fitting, exponential

I am trying to apply a best-fit curve to the data below. I am expecting the data to follow a curve of `p1=p/dist^2`, where p would be my only parameter. I am not quite getting the curve I was expecting, any ideas as to what miht help?

Thank you very much, let me know if I need to provide anything else to answer this question!

```
dist = (1,2,3,3)
ypos = np.arange(len(dist))
power1 = [0.33, 0.017, 0.0011, 0]
power2 = [05.87, 3.34, 1.65, .035]

def func(p,dist):
    return p/(dist**2)
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, dist, array1,p0=[5])
print(popt)
```

Comment: Please add a link to the data.

Comment: Data added in my initial posting.

Answer (score 0):

When I make a scatterplot of the data you posted, it looks more like a pulse or peak equation would be needed, and I could not get a good fit using the equation you have in your code. Here is my scatterplot code and image.

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequency_a = np.array([1.0, 2.6, 5.1, 7.6, 1.01, 1.26, 1.51, 1.76, 2.01, 2.26])
dB_a = np.array([0.000, 0.001, 0.045, 0.099, 0.413, 1.004, 2.277, 1.529, 1.031, 0.919])


plt.plot(frequency_a, dB_a, 'o') # plot the raw data
plt.ylim(-0.5, 2.0)
plt.xlim(0.0, 8.0)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplot]

Comment: Okay, that is a great point! Do you have any advice on still how I can add a trend line based off of that? I have never done any sort of best-fit in python before and understand the concept, but am pretty lost on the coding itself.

Comment: I do not see any sort of straight line trend in the scatterplot, so I cannot offer advice on how to make one here.

Comment: I am looking for a 1/(x^2) relationship. So for example, a/(x^2) where a would be my only parameter.

Comment: I changed my question with a different, much more simplified dataset to hopefully make it easier to understand. I'm sorry!